# How do multiple displays work on a AMD 785G / ATI HD 4200 motherboard?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I just ordered a ASUS M4A785TD-V EVO which has the AMD 785G chipset and HD4200 integrated graphic. The board has VGA, DVI, and HDMI outputs. I'm wondering how many outputs I can run at once, and from what connectors? My guess is that I can only use the VGA, and either the DVI or the HDMI in a dual setup. But not the HDMI and the DVI at the same time. Is this correct?

If I have devices plugged into both the HDMI and the DVI ports is there a way to choose between which port I want to use? I have a dual 19" monitor setup, as well as a LCD TV. I'd like to run the VGA and the DVI into my two monitors, and then the HDMI to my TV. Then when I want to watch something on the TV I'd like to be able to switch over from the DVI to the HDMI. Is this possible with out crawling under my desk and unplugging/plugging things in?

**Update**

I found the following in the manual off ASUS's website, which confirms my original suspicion that HDMI and DVI can't be used at the same time. But I'd still like to know if it's possible through software to switch between using the HDMI and DVI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use all the connections on separated displays on most graphic cards